# Timing desktop environment initialization

Tags: gnome, performance, desktop-environment, optimization

Is there a way to time desktop environment initialization and perhaps identify delaying candidates?

Answer (score 0):

Every DE in Linux has its own launch script, e.g. for XFCE its `startxfce4`. You can find them in `/usr/share/xsessions`.

Now to get timing information you can open a failsafe session, i.e. plain `xterm`, and run this command:

```
strace -tt -fF -o /tmp/xfce4.log startxfce4
```

Mind that you'll get a truly huge log. Run `man strace` for more info.